# SAT Solving for Optimization

Tags: optimization, satisfiability, conjunctive-normal-form

Suppose you have a CNF formula with some variables marked special.
Is there a way to make a SAT Solver (say, minisat) find a solution maximizing the number of special variables assigned to true?

Comment: You could create a cardinality constraint (cf. http://www.carstensinz.de/papers/CP-2005.pdf) to enforce the lower bound of special variables set to true. This is not a true optimization, but you delimit the search space. By increasing the cardinality threshold until UNSAT, you get your maximum "by hand".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you (I) want is called Partial Max Sat.  There is a solver called qmaxsat, which seems to work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if all of these can handle the indication of special variables, but at least [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem) gives some direction for the search:

> There are several solvers submitted to the last Max-SAT Evaluations:
>
> - Branch and Bound based: Clone, MaxSatz (based on Satz), IncMaxSatz, IUT_MaxSatz, WBO.
> - Satisfiability based: SAT4J, QMaxSat.
> - Unsatisfiability based: msuncore, WPM1, PM2.

Checking the description for all of them should be managable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PBC  solver such as minisat+   http://minisat.se/MiniSat+.html
They solve regular CNF files with additional constraints called pseudo Boolean constraints
Minisat+ also supports optimization of such constraints 
and from my understanding it solves your problem

Let x1, .... xn be the variables  you want to maximize the number o truth assignments
Then you can define the constraints
maximize +1 x1 .....  +1 xn
minisat+ solves such optimization problems